# multi-agent frameworks and web application development

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, multi-agent

Most of the java based web applications with multi agent frameworks are developed using JSP . can multi-agent framework like JADE be used with spring MVC framework? advice please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be used.Spring MVC can also use Beetl,Freemarker and so on.